# Required: android.support.v7.app.ActionBar Found: void

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to do this:

```
ActionBar toolbar = getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

but it says: 
Required: android.support.v7.app.ActionBar Found: void. 
Don't know what to do, hope someone can help. thanks

It also says this: 
`ActionBar.setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.android.support) less... (Ctrl+F1) 
This API has been flagged with a restriction that has not been met.  Examples of API restrictions: * Method can only be invoked by a subclass * Method can only be accessed from within the same library (defined by the Gradle library group id) .* Method can only be accessed from tests. . You can add your own API restrictions with the @RestrictTo annotation.

After that i used this:

```
ActionBar toolbar = getSupportActionBar();
toolbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and i am getting this exeption now:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.hfad.appmovienav, PID: 13025
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.hfad.appmovienav/com.hfad.appmovienav.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2718)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:117)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:56)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:31)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java:31)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:198)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
                      at com.hfad.appmovienav.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:24)
                      at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1173)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2708)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
Application terminated.
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Get the action bar or set the parameter?
I also wonder why you call that method? I don't think you are supposed to use that one, but rather `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ActionBar toolbar = getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

in above line you getting the return void value from the setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true). So for it you need to do :

```
ActionBar toolbar = getSupportActionBar();
toolbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And dont forget to extends your activity to AppCompatActivity 
like :

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

and add style :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

and use this style in manifest :

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```